# Angular regex filter on multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am learning angular with a simple table filter app and have run into some issues.

I am trying to implement a regex filter in Angular 1.4 so that users can filter certain inputs with multiple values. Additionally I have some simple greater than inputs on other fields. I've attempted to roll out a regex filter from a previous SO answer (albeit for v1.1) but cannot apply it to the two inputs that currently only string match.

Filter:

```
$scope.regex = function(){
  return function(input, field, regex) {
    var patt = new RegExp(regex);
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(patt.test(input[i][field]))
            out.push(input[i]);
    }
  return out;
  };
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Plunker example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekUFOLiabK6BXECK5lKp?p=info) with regex filter in controller but not applied in template.

Comment: If you want to use your own filter then you should [register](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) one.

Comment: Added answer based on suggestion to register with app rather than attach to scope (method from previous SO post)

Answer (score 0):

Solved based on input from @zeroflagL

```
appName.filter('regex', function() {
  return function(input, field, regex) {
      var patt;
      var out = [];
      if (regex === undefined) {
        patt = new RegExp(regex);
      }
      else {
        patt = new RegExp(regex.toLowerCase());
      }
      if(input === undefined) {
          return out;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
          if(patt.test(input[i][field].toLowerCase()))
              out.push(input[i]);
      }
    return out;
  };
});
```

and was able to use it in my ng-repeat with:

```
regex:'fieldname':scopeFilter.propertyForFieldName
```